# A property of first-countable spaces

Tags: general-topology

Wikipedia says that one of the most important properties of first-countable spaces is that given any subset $A$ of a topological space $(X,\tau)$ we have the following equivalence :
$x\in \bar A \iff \exists(a_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in A^{\mathbb{N}} : lim\ a_{n}=x $. So without this property in a topological space the equivalence fails more precisely the part (P) $x\in \bar A \implies \exists(a_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in A^{\mathbb{N}} : lim\ a_{n}=x$. Now if we consider the space $(\mathbb{R},\tau_{C})$ where $\tau_{C}$ is the cofinite topology then this space is not first countable, yet I can't seem to find an example where (P) fails since in the cofinite topology if $x_{n}$ is a sequence then any point in the space is a limit of $x_{n}$.

Comment: On that same wikipedia page, the example of the ordinal space $\omega_1+1$ is given. In that space, $\omega_1$ is in the closure of $[0,\omega_1)$ but there is no sequence in there that has $\omega_1$ as a limit point.

Comment: I'm afraid the ordinals are beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Also, for a general topological space, a limit of a sequence is a set, so already the cofinite topology fails, because $\lim a_n = X$, for any sequence $a_n$ in $X$.

Comment: @DanRust misleading. You mean that limits need not be unique. Limits are points not sets. A sequence can have many limits, but the limit is *not* the same as the set of limits of a sequence. Be precise.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma What horrible notation... So if $a$ and $b$ are both limits of $x_n$, then $\lim x_n =a$ and $\lim x_n = b$. So,..... $a=b$. Yeah I'd rather not.

Comment: @DanRust limit is **not** a function. The **complete** statement is $\lim x_n=a$ which has a definite meaning. The statement $\lim x_n =b$ can also be true for a different $b$. For so-called US spaces we can conclude from these statements that $a=b$ holds, but that's a special property (close to Hausdorff).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I'm saying the use of the equality symbol here is poor notation. The right hand side is an element of a space. The left hand side is a property that the right hand side satisfies. My preference would be to say $\lim x_n$ is the set of all points which are limits of the sequence, and then write $a \in \lim x_n$ if $a$ happens to be a limit of the sequence $x_n$.

Comment: @DanRust You could do that of course, if you explained it at the introduction of limits in a text book. I’ve seen it done though the set then often has a capital L, e.g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia page says that a first countable space is Fréchet-Urysohn, which is a fancy name for the property that the closure of set is precisely the set of possible sequential limits from that set.

As it happens, the cofinite topology on an uncountable set is an example of a Fréchet-Urysohn space that is not first countable (so this desirable property is not equivalent to being first countable). So there no example exists.

A better example in this vein is the co-countable topology on say $\Bbb R$. Also not first countable but as any convergent sequence is eventually constant certainly not Fréchet-Urysohn as well.